# WordpressHEADLESS and Gatsby: base url wrong after executing gatsby build

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, gatsby, headless

I was developing my website executing frontend gatsby on localhost:8000, than I needed to temporarily host that on our company server, so what I did is add this line in gatsby-config.js

```
module.exports = {
  pathPrefix: `/michelle/Gatsby-WP/public/`,  
}
```

And than executing a gatsby build like this

```
gatsby build --prefix-paths
```

Than I moved the /public folder on the server via FTP. The website works just fine on the server now, I can access is on https://example.com/michelle/Gatsby-WP/public and all the links in the navigation bar are right.

I have to continue develop locally now (so, back on localhost:8000) so I did the following steps:

1. Comment out the line I previously added with pathPrefix from gatsby-config.js
2. gatsby clean
3. gatsby develop

For some reason now, all the paths on the page are wrong on localhost. It is still trying to go via server. I access the index.js page on localhost:8000, but when I try to click on a link to another page, it tries to go to
**https://example.com/name-of-page** instead of **localhost:8000/name-of-page**

If it is of any use, this is the part of my code in header component where I return:

```
// "Menu" is an array of all pages in Wordpress which I access via GraphQL
// item.acf.slug looks like this "/name-of-page"

   return (
       <>
       <Ul  open={open}>
       {Menu.map((item) => ( 
           <ListItem>
               <Link to={item.acf.slug}>{item.title}</Link> 
           </ListItem>
       ))}
       </Ul >
       </>
   )
```

Answer (score 0):

For the in-app links, Gatsby handles the prefix automatically. However, for those path names that are built manually, you have the auxiliary [`withPrefix`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/previews-deploys-hosting/path-prefix/#add-the-path-prefix-to-paths-using-withprefix) function that prepends your prefix in production (but doesn’t during development where paths don’t need to be prefixed).

Applied to your use-case, should be something like this:

```
import { withPrefix } from "gatsby"


   return (
       <>
       <Ul  open={open}>
       {Menu.map((item) => ( 
           <ListItem>
               <Link to={withPrefix(item.acf.slug)}>{item.title}</Link> 
           </ListItem>
       ))}
       </Ul >
       </>
   )
```

Comment: I tested your solution but it doesnt seems to work, it still trying to get to page links on the server :(

Comment: it doesnt work only locally, because eveything works on the server version :)